# How do assets work in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to use jQuery/Bootstrap/other 3rd party js in my Rails app but I cannot understand how Rails work in terms of how it references those scripts.

In my Gem file I have:

```
gem 'jquery-rails',   '4.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',     '5.0.2'
```

and I see that Rails includes the following in assets/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Does that mean that Rails will include jQuery for every screen that my App has?

**What if I want to use a 3rd party only for some screens, not every screen**. **How can I accomplish that?**

And I couldn't find jQuery.min.js anywhere in my Rails project. Where it is **located**?. I've been searching in the following: **app/assets/javascripts**, **vendor/assets/javascripts**, **lib/assets** but no *jQuery/jQuery UI* script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes it will include it on every single screen rendered using the default layout (*app/views/layouts/application.html.erb*)
2. The jquery/sass/bootstrap css/js files live in the gems directory (somewhere deeply inside your ruby installation directory). So they are outside of your project, and sprockets extracts them from that external directory.
3. To avoid including those files on every single page you just need to create an another layout which will not reference the application.js file.

To include difference scripts using on different pages with the same layout you can use the *content_for* helper, there is quiet a lot of things to change, so:

app/views/layouts/application.html

```
# remove this
<% javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

# and add this
<%= yield :scripts %>
```

Next in all your views you can add something like this (anywhere in the file):

```
<% content_for :scripts do %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<% end %>
```

That specific example will just include the application.js with dependencies on some pages, and will include nothing on other pages. Generally you can create more than one manifest file (many application.js-like files.) But if you are not really comfortable with sprockets it will be much simpler for you to just put the regular js files into the public directory and then include them using something like:

```
<% content_for :scripts do %>
  <script src="javascripts/jquery.js" ></script>
  <script src="javascripts/pagination.js" ></script>
<% end %>
```

And the *javascripts/jquery.js* should be available in your public directory.

Comment: So, basically, for a 3rd party (like a pagination-table, which I do not need it on every screen) I should manually copy the script to my rails project so that I can reference it with script tag ? But with this approach I always have to manually update every 3rd party which is not okay at all. Creating a new layout sounds like a bad idea to me. Maybe I want the same html structure like the current layout but with different javascripts and for this a new layout wouldn't be worth it

Comment: If you look inside application.html.erb there is a piece of code like `javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true`. It add the *application.js* with all the dependencies on the page. You replace that line with any custom logic, that will import only the scripts you need.

Comment: Also you can learn about `content_for` rails helper, which can be used to specify the scripts to import in the views instead of the layout.

Comment: And how can I include jquery/other 3rd party (installed using gem file, because as you said, the scripts are located outside my app) for a particular screen with **content_for**?

Comment: I've added an example to the answer.